# Multithreading: waiting for a thread to finish so I can retry a deadlock

Tags: c#, sql, .net, multithreading, forms

I have 2 threads, and I have to make the successful thread wait while the deadlocked one retries. The current code only works for the first loop, because the successful thread exits.

I've tried using Thread.Join() with no success.

How can I make the thread in which 'success' is 'true' to wait for the for the deadlocked thread to finish?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure1));
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure2));

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();
        }


        private void procedure1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread 1");
            bool success = false;
            int retryCount = 1;
            while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure1"), connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        success = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Number == 1205)
                    {
                        if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlocked");
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                        retryCount++;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void procedure2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread 2");
            bool success = false;
            int retryCount = 1;
            while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure2"), connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        success = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Number == 1205)
                    {
                        if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlocked");
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                        retryCount++;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The SQL procedures used for the deadlock:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE deadlockP1
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
        UPDATE Employee SET position = 'handler' WHERE employee_code = 4037;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
        UPDATE Shop SET shop_name = 'TITANUS' WHERE shop_code = 2019;
    COMMIT TRAN;    
END

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE deadlockP2
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;
        UPDATE Shop SET shop_name = 'TITANUS' WHERE shop_code = 2019;
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
        UPDATE Employee SET position = 'manager' WHERE employee_code = 4037;
    COMMIT TRAN;    
END
```

Comment: join is the solution to your problem. Could add your code segment to show how exactly did you use join?

Comment: _"I have 2 threads, and I have to make the successful thread wait while the deadlocked one retries. "_ - do you, though?

Comment: @Fildor I also am confused by the requirement they must wait on each other. Maybe there is other implementations that arent listed where they have to be in-sync

Comment: The requirement is that I have to retry the the deadlocked thread a number of times (3 in my code), until it is considered finished ('retryCount is '3').

Comment: Why does that requirement imply that the other thread waits?

Comment: It doesn't, but I guess if I want to retry the procedure, I have to make the other thread wait, isn't it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make the thread in which 'success' is 'true' to wait for the for the deadlocked thread to finish?

Consider using a `Barrier` if all threads must finish at similar times and wait for each other. Otherwise I recommend using `Join`(see below).

> A group of tasks cooperate by moving through a series of phases, where each in the group signals it has arrived at the Barrier in a given phase and implicitly waits for all others to arrive. The same Barrier can be used for multiple phases.

When you use a barrier it basically means that all the threads you assign to be in the barrier have to all reach a "checkpoint" before each can continue.

Here's a quick example of what that might look like:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // create a barrier with 2 slots
    private Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2);

    private void procedure1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread 1");
        bool success = false;
        int retryCount = 1;
        while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure1"), connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 1205)
                {
                    if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlocked");
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                    retryCount++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // wait for all other tasks in barrier to get to this checkpoint before returning
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
    }

    private void procedure2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread 2");
        bool success = false;
        int retryCount = 1;
        while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure2"), connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 1205)
                {
                    if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlocked");
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                    retryCount++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // wait for all other tasks in barrier to get to this checkpoint before returning
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
    }
}
```

It should be noted though that similar effects can be accomplished using [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0)(async)  and [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0)(sync), that are easier to implement along with [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=net-5.0)(but you said you didn't want to use/couldn't use join).

If you want to reconsider using `Join`, consider passing a reference of the thread you want to wait on to the other thread. Join blocks the current thread(waits) while the *instance* of the thread that it calls `Join` on finishes up.

Here's how `Join` works in a nutshell, just make sure not to get two threads trying to wait for each other. You'll be waiting a long time for them to figure it out.

```cs
void ThreadOne(Thread other)
{
    // do work
    // ...
    
    // wait for other to finish
    other?.Join();
}

void ThreadTwo()
{
    // do work
    // ...
}
```

When you use `Join`s you run into a problem when two tasks have to wait on eachother. In your example you want to wait(Join) when the current thread has finished it's work, but the other hasn't. How do we know when the other thread has finished it's work?

We should use a [**sentinel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value to notify other threads that work has either been done, or still needs to be completed.

We can use a bunch of things for sentinel values, from encapsulating variables, class variables and even `WaitHandles`.

If we use a sentinel value we can use `Join` by passing each Thread a reference to each other.

Here's what that might look like:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // create sentinels
    bool thread1Status = false;
    bool thread2Status = false;

    // create a spot to store the threads so they can reference each other
    Thread thread1;
    Thread thread2;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure1));
        thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(procedure2));

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
    }

    private void procedure1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread 1");
        bool success = false;
        int retryCount = 1;
        while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure1"), connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;
                    
                    // notify other thread that we finished work
                    thread1Status = true;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 1205)
                {
                    if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlocked");
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                    retryCount++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // wait for the other thread to finish work if it hasn't
        if(success && thread2Status == false)
        {
             thread2?.Join();
        }
    }

    private void procedure2(Thread other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread 2");
        bool success = false;
        int retryCount = 1;
        while ((retryCount <= 3) && success == false)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("execProcedure2"), connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    success = true;

                    // notify other thread that we finished work
                    thread2Status = true;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 1205)
                {
                    if (retryCount == 1) Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlocked");
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 deadlock retry number " + retryCount.ToString());
                    retryCount++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // wait for the other thread to finish work if it hasn't
        if(success && thread1Status == false)
        {
             thread1?.Join();
        }
    }
}
```